# Wrong URL when trying to verify it on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to verify the URL of my page using Selenium IDE.

I use, in order:

- a `//` command to simply make the page load (irrelevant)
- an execute script to store URL
- an assert to verify that URL

The URL it returns is something like chrome `extension://mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd/bootstrap.html`. I get that this is because of the way Selenium IDE launches pages, but how do I do to get the actual URL?

[image: My Test]

Comment: BTW, the proper tag for this question is [selenium-ide], not [selenium].